# How to display ProgressBar in the form of a Notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-progressbar

> I'm Developing an android application to download .mp3 from Server.
>   When clicked on the download button ProgressBar will appear,displaying the
>   percentage on screen.

This works fine. Now i want to make that download work in background by Showing Notification with a ProgressBar

can anyone help me to find a code to Use the Service and Building Notification?Thank You

My MainActivity.java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    final MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
    //---------------------
    Clone c=new Clone();

    //------------------
    // button to show progress dialog
    Button btnShowProgress;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ImageView my_image;
    // Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

    // File url to download
    private static String file_url = "http://www.eecindia.co.in/up/01%20-%20Pretham%20-%20Oruthikku%20Pinnil%20[Maango.me].mp3";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // show progress bar button
        btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);
        // Image view to show image after downloading
        my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        /**
         * Show Progress bar click event
         * */
        btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //----------------------------------------------
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Select The Extension To Download...");
                builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]
                                {".mp3", ".mp4", ".txt", ".srt"},
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                                // of the selected item
                                switch (which) {
                                    case 0:
                                        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Jithin's/");
                                        if (!folder.exists()) {
                                            try {
                                                folder.mkdirs();
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                                System.out.println("Default Save Path Creation Error:" + folder);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        c.setA(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Jithin's/downloadedfile.mp3");
                                        // starting new Async Task
                                        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);

                                        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                        break;
                                    case 1:
                                       ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                        File folde = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Jithin's/");
                                        if (!folde.exists()) {
                                            try {
                                                folde.mkdirs();
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                                System.out.println("Default Save Path Creation Error:" + folde);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        c.setA(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Jithin's/downloadedfile.mp4");
                                        // starting new Async Task
                                        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
                                        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        File fold = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Jithin's/");
                                        if (!fold.exists()) {
                                            try {
                                                fold.mkdirs();
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                                System.out.println("Default Save Path Creation Error:" + fold);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        c.setA(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Jithin's/downloadedfile.txt");
                                        // starting new Async Task
                                        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
                                        break;
                                    case 3:
                                        File fol = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Jithin's/");
                                        if (!fol.exists()) {
                                            try {
                                                fol.mkdirs();
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                                System.out.println("Default Save Path Creation Error:" + fol);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        c.setA(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Jithin's/downloadedfile.srt");
                                        // starting new Async Task
                                        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                builder.create().show();
                /////-------------------------------------

            }
        });

    }


    /**
     * Showing Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case progress_bar_type:
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Downloading File. Please Wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setMax(100);
                pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
                return pDialog;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to download file
     * */
    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread
         * Show Progress Bar Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                // 6yi7 conection.connect();
                conection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");

                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream to write file
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(c.getA());

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            try {
                pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
            } catch (Exception d) {
                Log.d("Error .. ", d.getMessage());
            }
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task
         * Dismiss the progress dialog
         **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Downloaded Succesfully.. check Jithin's folder 2 see file...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
        }

    }
        //---------------------------------



    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this answer-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128121/how-to-show-the-progress-bar-in-notification-area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use foreground `Notification`.Here is your [Example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/FakePlayer)
project demonstrating the use of `startForeground()`.

Comment: Shows Error on PlayServices .java    //( note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Fake Player",
                    "Now Playing: \"Ummmm, Nothing\"",
                    pi);
            note.flags|=Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;  ) This Line

Comment: Try this example : http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/

Comment: that site is not available

Comment: Try this http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/09/simple-android-foreground-service-example/